# How do I turn this synchronous method into one that returns a Task?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a method that more or less calls three different Async methods and then returns a "Result" object containing a success message. Any of those three Async methods may throw a `SshException`, so I've placed all three within a `try{}catch{}` that traps the `AggregateException`, handles the `SshException`, and then returns a *failure* result object.

Since I'm on .Net 4.0, I can't use async/await (which I believe would solve my problem easily), but I would like to turn the method into one that returns a Task containing one of two results:

1. "Success" if all three previous tasks completed successfully.
2. "Failure" if *any* of the previous tasks faulted. Ideally, task execution would stop at the first canceled task too (e.g. TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted for the three work Tasks).

Here's some sample code:

```
public UploadResult UploadFileToDir(string dir, string text)
{
    try
    {
        SftpClient.Cd(dir).Wait();  // This is a Task
        var filename = this.GetFilename().Result;  // This is also a Task
        SftpClient.WriteFile(filename, text).Result;  // This is the last Task
        return UploadResult.Success;
    }
    catch(AggregateException agg)
    {
        if(agg.InnerException is SshException)
        {
            return UploadResult.Failure;
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) which allows you to use `async`/`await` in .NET 4 projects.  That would allow you to write:

```
public async Task<UploadResult> UploadFileToDir(string dir, string text)
{
    try
    {
        await SftpClient.Cd(dir)
        var filename = await this.GetFilename();
        await SftpClient.WriteFile(filename, text);
        return UploadResult.Success;
    }
    catch(SshException ex)
    {
        return UploadResult.Failure;
    }
}
```

Without that, you'd have to make each task run as a continuation on the previous, and return the final Task continuation, or just take your existing code and wrap it in a `Task.Factory.StartNew` call (which isn't really good either, as you're then doing async over sync over async, which is very inefficient).  This creates a lot of code, and makes the overall flow much more difficult to follow.

Comment: Nice tip about Microsoft.Bcl.Async, I didn't know that was available!
I tried your second alternative (make each task run as a continuation on the previous) before posting, but I wasn't able to figure out how to catch and return an `UploadResult` from the `this.GetFilename()` continuation if *that* Task threw an SshException. Was I missing something there?

Comment: @nemec The problem is that you have to have each task check for the exception, and rethrow to the next, and then have the last continuation handle it - or you need to change the return types of the intermediate tasks to handle it.  It's ugly, which is why I said this is such a nicer approach ;)